# Makefile target-specific variables ignore others in conditional assignment

Tags: gnu-make

Given this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: plus cond set

plus: export FOO += plus
plus:
    @echo plus is $(FOO)

cond: export FOO ?= cond
cond: plus
    @echo cond is $(FOO)

set: export FOO := set
set: cond
    @echo set is $(FOO)
```

I expect `make set` to output:

```
plus is set plus
cond is set
set is set
```

but instead I get:

```
plus is cond plus
cond is cond
set is set
```

The fact that `plus is cond plus` tells me that I am right in thinking that target-specific variables are in scope for target-specific variables of prerequisites. So why does the conditional assignment `FOO ?= cond` not respect that `FOO` is already set? Is this a bug?

Whether or not it is a bug, and without using `.SECONDEXPANSION`, how do I get the desired behavior, which is that `make cond` outputs `cond is cond` but `make set` gives me `cond is set`?

Answer (score 0):

It was [filed as a bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?18305) but made into an enhancement request. I think it is a bug.

> The way conditional variables work is that the "conditionality" of the variable is determined when the variable is assigned (in immediate context), not when the variable is expanded.  When we evaluate the variable assignment in "lib: TARGET ?= two" we don't have the inheritance of the "all" target in scope yet, because that doesn't happen until make actually runs the makefile.  So at the time that we evaluation "conditionality" there is no other value in scope.
>
> Now actually I lied a little bit because even if you set "TARGET = global" as a global setting, which clearly IS in-scope when the target-specific variable is set, the result will still be "two".  That's because conditionality only looks at variables assigned in the same scope.

In the easy case where the name of the variable does not matter (it does not propagate further), you can fix it with an explicit conditional in either of these ways:

```
cond: export FOO_cond = $(or $(FOO),cond)
cond: plus
    @echo cond is $(FOO_cond)
    @echo cond is $(or $(FOO),cond)
```

But these are not solutions if you want `FOO` to propagate further, e.g. to prerequisites of `cond` like `plus`. The best workaround I have found so far is to introduce another target:

```
cond: export FOO = cond
cond: cond_w_override

cond_w_override: plus
    @echo cond is $(FOO)

set: export FOO := set
set: cond_w_override
    @echo set is $(FOO)
```

but note that now you have to chose the right prerequisite depending on whether or not you want to override the default value the `cond` has for `FOO`.